# SQL Server : connect to local host after change win 10 password

Tags: sql-server

I have changed my Windows 10 password and can not connect to the localhost with my windows authentification any more. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Unfortunately I am not able to find the right `sa` password either.

Is there any way to refresh the Windows authentification?

This is the error I recive:

> 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Comment: Did you configure SQL Server to run under *your* account when you installed it?

Comment: Did you try logoff/logon?